# Return only values between two values in array?

Tags: node.js

I've got this array.

```
const array = [0, 5.476, 11.251, 31.916, 44.007, 53.911, 58.628, 65.729, 75.222, 88.849, 100]
```

How would I go about only returning values between `23.419` and `46.839` without calling by index. I wouldn't be surprised if there's a native function for this, as to why my question is short. Thanks.

Comment: you can use filter function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `filter` function :

```js
array.filter(item => item >= 23.419 && item <= 46.839);
```

Comment: Interesting, had a brief look at filters, what exactly do they perform? This is great btw.

Comment: you can check the documentation it is well explained : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

Comment: Same MDN reference en anglais https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter